# How to filter on a search box a boolean in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want my boolean field which is displayed as 'Approved' and 'Not Approved' in the frontend, is it possible for me to filter this as displayed in the frontend?

My filtering logic

```
$search = '%'.$this->search . '%';
        $comments = Comment
        ::where('title', 'like', $search)
       ->orWhere('name', 'like', $search)
       ->orWhere('email', 'like', $search)
       ->orWhere('message', 'like', $search)
       ->orWhere('approved', 'like', $search)
       ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')       
       ->paginate($this->paginate);
```

I can only search the approved column as 0 and 1.

Comment: For the approved orWhere condition, just use $this->search instead of $search and change 'like' to '=' maybe?

Comment: So you are searching by single value.
maybe mapping the values to true or false is your best bet.
approved to true, and not approved to false, and skip filtering if not any approved or not approved. otherwise you can skip filtering by this value.

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din is there a sample code or a visual that I can reference to?

Comment: something like this: `$is_approved = $this->search == "Approved"; $is_not_approved = $this->search == "Not Approved";` then in your query: `->when($is_approved, function ($query) { return $query->where('approved, true); })->when($is_not_approved, function($query) { return $query->where('approved', false); });`

Comment: considering both values because I think you need to skip the filter if search is not one of ['Approved', 'Not Approved']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below query -

```
$search = '%'.$this->search . '%';
$searchInput = $this->search;

$comments = Comment::where('title', 'like', $search)->where(function ($q) use ($searchInput, $search) {
    $q->orWhere('name', 'like', $search);
    $q->orWhere('email', 'like', $search);
    $q->orWhere('message', 'like', $search);
    $q->orWhereRaw("(CASE WHEN approved = 1 THEN 'Approved' ELSE 'Not Approved' END) LIKE '%$searchInput%'");
})->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($this->paginate);
```

Comment: This gave me an error
`
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%%' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `comments` where `title` like %% or `name` like %% or `email` like %% or `message` like %% or `approved` like %% or (CASE WHEN approved = 0 THEN 'Approved' ELSE 'Not Approved' END) LIKE %%)
`

Comment: I can type the approved but it is not filtering, it  displays the whole data.

Comment: It removed the error but the filter doesn't work, it  shows me the whole data and doesn't removed the for approval.

Comment: My bad, it works now, my input was For Approval not Not Approved. My mistake